# Issue with creating nested map using streams and collectors

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

```
class QuizAnswers {
  List<CheckboxAnswer> checkBoxAnswers;
}

class CheckboxAnswer {
  int questionId;
  // The indices of the selected answer choices
  List<Integer> answer_selections;
}
```

The input to my function is a `List<QuizAnswers>`.

I want to create an output of  `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>>` that maps `<CheckboxAnswer.questionId : <CheckboxAnswer.answer_selection, total count of answer_selection>`. In other words, I want to create a nested map that maps each multiple selection quiz question to a map representing the total number of selections on each answer choice of that quiz question.

Suppose the input `List<QuizAnswers> quizAnswersList` as:

```
[ {questionId: 1, answer_selection: [1,2]},    
  {questionId: 1, answer_selection:[1,2,3,4]},  
  {questionId: 2, answer_selection:[3]},   
  {questionId: 2, answer_selection:[1]} ]
```

Then I would want the output to be:

```
{1 : {1:2, 2:2, 3:1, 4:1}, 2: {1:1, 3:1}}
```

Because the question with `Id = 1` received two selections on answer choice `2` and `1` and `1` selection on answer choice `3` and `4` while the question with `Id=2` had `1` selection on answer choice `1` and `3`.

I have tried

```
quizAnswersList.stream()
            .flatMap(
                quizAnswers ->
                    quizAnswers.getCheckboxAnswers().stream())
            .collect(
                answer -> {
                  return Collectors.groupingBy(
                      answer.getQuestionId(),
                      answer.getAnswerSelections().stream()
                          .collect(
                              Collectors.groupingBy(
                                  answerSelection -> answerSelection, 
                                  Collectors.counting())));
                        });
```

Which is giving me an error that the first collect() is not taking the right arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you were close, your usage of collectors is syntactically incorrect.

Firstly, the required method [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) expects a collector (*there's also another flavor of* `collect()` *that expect tree "functions": supplier, accumulator and combiner; don't confuse them*), that's the correct syntax:

```
.collect(MyCollector);
```

Now, regarding the [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)) collector. We need its version that expects a `classifier` *function* and a *downstream collector*:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(function, AnotherCollector);
```

And as a downstream collector we need to provide [`flatMapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)). Which expects a function that should transform each `CheckboxAnswer` into a stream of *answer selection values* (*in order to be able to map each of them to its count*), and a *downstream collector*. In turn as the *downstream* of `flatMapping()` again we need to provide `groupingBy()` and `counting()` as its *downstream collector*.

The final structure of *collectors* will be the following:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(function, // <- getting a question Id
    Collectors.flatMapping(function,     // <- obtaining `answer selection values` as a stream of Integer
        Collectors.groupingBy(function,  // <- Function.identity() is used to retain a `answer selection` without changes
            Collectors.counting()        // <- obtaining a count for each `answer selection`
);
```

Now, let's put all the things together.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<QuizAnswers> quizAnswersList =
        List.of(new QuizAnswers(List.of(new CheckboxAnswer(1, List.of(1,2)),
                                        new CheckboxAnswer(1, List.of(1,2,3,4)))),
                new QuizAnswers(List.of(new CheckboxAnswer(2, List.of(3)),
                                        new CheckboxAnswer(2, List.of(1)))));

    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>> answerSelectionToCountById = quizAnswersList.stream()
        .map(QuizAnswers::getCheckBoxAnswers)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            CheckboxAnswer::getQuestionId,
                Collectors.flatMapping(checkboxAnswer -> checkboxAnswer.getAnswerSelections().stream(),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        Collectors.counting()))));
    
    answerSelectionToCountById.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " : " + v));
}
```

*Output*

```
1 : {1=2, 2=2, 3=1, 4=1}
2 : {1=1, 3=1}
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the error 
```incompatible types: inference variable K has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.lang.Integer
    lower bounds: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer> [compiler.err.prob.found.req]```
 on the first collect function.

I believe this code would work if CheckboxAnswer.getAnswerSelections() returned an int but since it returns a List<Int>, this would not work.

Comment: @tigh75 There was a bug, fixed the answer and provided the demo, now it runs correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is may be easier to get to the final result in two steps: After grouping by your `questionId` you need to map to your `answer_selections`. This can be done using `Collectors.mapping` so that you end up with an intermediate result of `Map<Integer,List<List<Integer>>>` which could look like something like:

```
Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> intermediate =
        quizAnswersList.stream()
                .flatMap(quizAnswers -> quizAnswers.getCheckBoxAnswers().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CheckboxAnswer::getQuestionId,
                                Collectors.mapping(CheckboxAnswer::getAnswer_selections, Collectors.toList())));

System.out.println(intermediate);
```

This will give you an output like:

```
{1=[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]], 2=[[3], [1]]}
```

Since the above is not what you realy wanted you need to do one more step and wrap the mapping which is done here

```
Collectors.mapping(CheckboxAnswer::getAnswer_selections, Collectors.toList())
```

in to `Collectors.collectingAndThen` to turn the values of above map which are of type list of lists to a `Map<Integer,Long>` which can be done like showed below (including the above step, which only was useful to explain the intermediate result, only the code below is needed):

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>> finalresult =
quizAnswersList.stream()
        .flatMap(quizAnswers -> quizAnswers.getCheckBoxAnswers().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CheckboxAnswer::getQuestionId,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.mapping(CheckboxAnswer::getAnswer_selections, Collectors.toList()),
                        lists -> lists.stream()
                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting())))));

System.out.println(finalresult);
```

which will give you the desired result

```
{1={1=2, 2=2, 3=1, 4=1}, 2={1=1, 3=1}}
```